# Compare the starttime input from user and compare it with the time now

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a property in my clas:

`public string Starttime`

This is a input value from the client side. Now I want this value to compare with the time of the computer.

Pseudo code:

```
if(inputvalue startime = time on the computer){
     //do something
}
else{

thread.sleep(100)

}
```

The syntax of the time must not be `Datetime` but only the time like 13:00, 13:00, 14:57 etc.

Which datatype is best to achieve this requirement?

Comment: so you say, you don't care about the date? only time in the format of `hh:mm` ? Do you want only to compare for equality? then why not using a `string` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using a `TimeSpan` to keep just the hours and minutes and you'll be good.

Alternatively, you can get the entire date and only compare the `TimeOfDay` property:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Now;
if(startTime.Hour == endTime.Hour && startTime.Minute == startTime.Minute)
{
    // Do what you do when they are equal...
}
else
{
    // They are not equal. Which is more likely.
}
```

Also, I'd advise using a `DateTime` object as opposed to a string for that.

**Update**

Another way to cater for the slight differences if you have a tolerance is as follows:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Now;  // Here I am assuming a tolerance of 2 seconds.
if(endTime.Subtract(startTime).Seconds <= 2)
{
    // Basically the same.
}
else
{
    // Different as far as we are concerned.
}
```

Comment: I would recomment using `startTime.Hour` & `startTime.Minute`. 1 second laag or not responding application and your trigger is gone...

Comment: @FelixD. I considered your suggestion and edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeSpan as the datatype. Here is the MSDN reference with all the methods and properties that you should have access to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TimeSpan` type to represent hours and minutes. It has a `Parse` method that will take your input string and convert it to a `TimeSpan`. Then you can compare the time with the current time, using `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var clientInput = "14:57";
    var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(clientInput);
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    Console.WriteLine("The start time is: {0}", startTime.ToString("hh\\:mm"));
    Console.WriteLine("The current time is: {0}", currentTime.ToString("hh\\:mm"));

    var difference = currentTime.Subtract(startTime);

    if ((int)difference.TotalMinutes == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's time to start!");
    }
    else if ((int)difference.TotalMinutes > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We should have started {0} minutes ago!",
            (int)difference.TotalMinutes);
    }            
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We will start in: {0} hours and {1} minutes.",
            -difference.Hours, -difference.Minutes);
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]